# android widget opens application with delay when clicked

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-widget

I have a widget which opens a qr scan screen in my application but, when I click widget it opens application with delay, when I put log within onReceive function I can see the logged text after like 1-2 seconds

And problem is within that period user can click multiple times widget which will call onReceive function multiple times which is not intended

below is my widger provider

```
class QrScanWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    fun updateAppWidget(
        context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetId: Int
    ) {
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_qr_scan).also {
            it.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_qr_scan, context.getString(R.string.qr_scan))
        }
        setOnItemClicks(views, context)
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == ON_ITEM_CLICK_ACTION && context != null) {
            NavigationUtils.getShowScreenPendingIntent(
                context,
                SCREEN_SCAN,
                null,
                true
            ).send()
        }
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
    }

    private fun setOnItemClicks(views: RemoteViews, context: Context) {
        val onItemClickIntent = Intent(context, QrScanWidgetProvider::class.java)

        onItemClickIntent.action = ON_ITEM_CLICK_ACTION
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(
            R.id.root_view, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, onItemClickIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val ON_ITEM_CLICK_ACTION =
            "ON_ITEM_CLICK_ACTION"
    }
}
```